# PHP mail body construct

Tags: php, sendmail

I can't seem to join (concatenate) these fields correctly. Basically we are using a mail api to a 3rd party back end and we can't change their fields. So to add new fields we need to add them to the comments section. I want to add

```
log in id ($loginID) 
their $internal=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

to the comments field `$inquiry = $_POST['TextField'] ;`

I need to format it as follows in the generated email:

**Log in** - xyz

**Host name** - xxxx

**Internal IP** - xxx

**Comments** - a;ldkjfalkdjf

Currently I have the following code, which when joined together returns nothing

```
$loginID = $_POST['loginID'] ;
$internal=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$inquiry = $_POST['$loginID' . '$internal' . '$hostname' . 'TextField'] ;

mail( "email@email.com", "subject",
"$inquiry"
"From: $email");
```

How can I group the desired data and format it better in the return email? thx!

Comment: your $inquery = $_POST also is wrong i believe per @Gazler

Answer (score 4):

```
$inquiry = $_POST['$loginID' . '$internal' . '$hostname' . 'TextField'] ;
```

That line looks wrong.  I think you mean:

```
$inquiry = $_POST['loginID'] . $internal . $hostname . $_POST['TextField'] ;
```

Or to format it like you said:

```
$inquiry = 'Log In - '.$_POST['loginID'].PHP_EOL;
$inquiry .= 'Host name - '.$hostname.PHP_EOL;
$inquiry .= 'Internal IP - '.$internal.PHP_EOL;
$inquiry .= 'Comments - : '.$_POST['TextField'].PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: +1 but i would recommand using PHP_EOL instead of `\n` due to server issues

Comment: Awesome, works better with PHP_EOL, should that be used in place of \n everywhere? I haven't used the end of line command before. Thanks for the quick help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful how you are structuring $inquiry:

> Message to be sent.
>
> Each line should be separated with a
>   LF (\n). Lines should not be larger
>   than 70 characters.
>
> Caution (Windows only) When PHP is
>   talking to a SMTP server directly, if
>   a full stop is found on the start of a
>   line, it is removed. To counter-act
>   this, replace these occurrences with a
>   double dot.

[PHP Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)